# Can someone explain why this edit was approved?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, language-versions

I asked an OP for clarification on his question, and he indicated that the question related to SQL Server 2012.  I edited the question, adding that information to it, and tagged it with sql-server-2012.  Someone came in and changed the tag to sql-server.

Am I misunderstanding how tags are applied?  Since a tag exists for sql-server-2012, and that's the version the question related to, shouldn't that tag be the one used?  I just want to make sure I'm making edits correctly.

The revision history is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54580473/revisions

Comment: That's actually very simple to understand if you think through it (especially about the purpose of tags). Can the problem be replaced across all (or most) versions of softwareX?: use tag softwareX. Is the problem specific to versionY of that software: use tags softwareX and softwareX-Y.

Comment: s/replaced/reproduced/ .. srry

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Version-specific tags are a bit complicated. They are a necessary evil, but they're often used inappropriately.

The secret is that **you should only use a version-specific tag when the question is *specifically related to* that version**. This is just a special case of the general rule that tags describe the question itself.

Consider another example. You are developing a web page using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Something isn't working, so you ask a question about it. Obviously, you tag it [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). You're doing your development on Windows: do you tag it [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)? No. Because the problem has nothing to do with Windows. What about a browser-specific tag? Not just because you happen to be using that browser. Only if you've found that the problem is *specific* to that browser (i.e., doesn't reproduce in other browsers).

Same thing here. If the question is about something *specific* in SQL Server 2012, or a problem that *only* occurs in SQL Server 2012, then a [sql-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) tag is appropriate.

As a mere indicator that the person happens to be using SQL Server 2012? No, that's not an appropriate use of the tag. Instead, that should just be mentioned in the body of the question.

Another rule when using version-specific tags is that they should always be *combined* with the "master" tag. So, if you *are* going to tag with [sql-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) because the problem is specific to that version, you should *also* tag with [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). Why? Because obviously the question is still related to SQL Server, and you want people who only monitor the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag (and not the litany of version-specific tags) to see it.

In this particular case, I don't know enough about SQL Server to decide whether this is a version-specific issue, so I have to defer that to you or another expert.

As for why the edit modifying yours was approved, you can see that [it was approved by the person who originally posted the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22147323), and the system gives them the authority to single-handedly approve edits to their own posts.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely confused as to when to use the version-specific tag.  I need to digest this.  Thanks for the answer, it definitely helps.

Comment: Try not to make it *too* complicated, @Johnny. If you think a version tag is needed, stick it on there. We trust you; that's why we give you tag editing privileges. But this is my rule of thumb, and I find it works pretty well in practice.

Comment: TBH this probably needs to be a FAQ article somewhere for easier linkage. What you've written here sums it up pretty well

Comment: Does Meta have tag wikis like SO? Maybe such a thing already exists, but if it doesn't it seems like there should be a list of canonical questions and answers.

Comment: @Andy Yes, Meta has tag wikis, but it also has one better: a [meta-tag:faq]. The FAQ index is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow).

Comment: @JohnnyBones TL;DR Far more people pay attention to [sql-server] than [sql-server-2012]. Remember, version-specific tags are more niche and we want the question to be in front of as many helpful eyes as possible.

Comment: I think this answer misses just one bit. If you are using a SQL Server feature introduced in some version, should the version tag be applied?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto is that feature only available on that version? I prefer that if there was a tag for said feature you use that tag, instead of the version you use.

Answer (score 12):

It was approved by the author of the post who has a binding vote. If you look at the review it shows only one person on it and that happens to be the author of the post.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22147323

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the difference between the two edits is merely two minutes. And the edit description says "*added* tag", not "*fixed*" or anything. There was just a two-minute window in which the new tag was visible in the primary view of the question, and the edit might very easily have been commited for consideration before that.

Especially with the author's vote and his not being around for too long, it could simply be nothing more than an oversight that he's unintentionally undone a part of your edit by approving the other one.