# Please clarify in the Help Center the guidance regarding tag hierarchy

Tags: support, tags, help-center

Way back in the history of Stack Overflow, one A to  [Implicit tagging hierarchy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58073/implicit-tagging-hierarchy) was:

> I don't think adding this kind of complexity would make the tag system better.

Given the clout of the user (`user:1`)  this has been taken by some<sup>†</sup> as official disapproval of any tag hierarchy, in particular when coupled with the wording between commas [in](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

An A [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380417/1505120) includes the advice:

> For example, when you tag with [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you *also* tag with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

in the context *"when you use a version-specific tag, you should also always tag with the "main" tag."* (ibid.).

A corresponding approach is also being taken in many cases other than for versions. For example [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and [google-sheets-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula) are each usually also tagged [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) <sub>(despite the existence of [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))</sub>.

There are pros and cons regarding a tag hierarchy, discussed interminably across much (all?) of Stack Exchange with discussion complicated by differences in interpretation of Help Center advice.

IF it is not intended to bar usage such as the Sheets example, please clarify the Help Center to that effect OR should such 'pairing' apply *only* to version tags, please clarify to *that* effect.

---

For example:

At present we have tags for [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) as well as [excel-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2013) (often 'paired' in line with the "[c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you *also* tag with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)" approach) but also [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) (and [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula)), [excel-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-import) (and [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import)), [excel-match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-match) (and [match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/match)). So it is quite possible for all five allowed tags to be of the pattern "excel-?", though I'd consider this overkill.

Already users are confused by the likes of [vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlookup) and [conditional-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting), for example, as each is Excel specific according to its Usage guide. Hence I created tags [gs-vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-vlookup) and [gs-conditional-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-conditional-formatting) for Google Sheets, though many other spreadsheets have corresponding functions. Without 'pairing' we might, eventually, end up with [vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlookup), [gs-vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-vlookup), `apple-numbers-vlookup`, `openoffice-calc-vlookup`, `libreoffice-calc-vlookup`, `gnumeric-vlookup` (and more for other spreadsheets I have not identified as yet having a tag of their own on SO) all just for the one concept ("looking up" whose *context* could be defined by a separate (application) tag, required regardless.

Also, there is already more than one screen full (36 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)) of tags containing `excel`, for example. Sorted "Popular" it is not easy to find the less popular ones (there is no obvious way to step forward one screen) such as [excel-2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2000), [excel-2002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2002), [excel-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2008). In my opinion little wonder that so many users fail to apply these where they should. And switching to the sorted "Name" option is not any easy way to find such tags either. First, since there is no index, is the difficulty of finding even where the "e?"s start and once there (today on page 399)
quite a long way to where the "ex?"s start (today page 439) when only able to advance with clicking at most two pages at a time.  It seems to me unlikely that anyone would bother, but if they did they might spot [excel-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-macro). Less so now but [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) with [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro) was a very popular pairing at one time (many thousands of Qs) and still over 1,000 Open Qs a present. It happens to be a synonym and without a Usage guide to provide any warning. Click on it and it redirects to  a tag whose Usage guide starts:

> THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL.

A mod has [stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380417/1505120):

> The tag system is designed to help experts find questions.

Experts will, hopefully, assist the less experienced with correct tagging but they need to be given the chance to do so. Unless the less experienced are "in the right ball park" for kick off the appropriate experts may never see a question that merits retagging – or it may take several edits (and 'bounces') to reach their field of view.

<sup>†</sup> Examples are clearer on other sites with fewer tags. For instance Web Applications has about 1,000 separate tags at present (SO more like 57,000) yet of those about 150 start "google" – not including about 15 starting "gmail", nor other Google offers.

<sub>There is already official approval of a tag hierarchy, albeit somewhat a special case, in the mandatory tags for Meta posts. (Though that element of the system might work better were usage restricted to *one* of the five at a time.)</sub>

Comment: [Like the poet said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281094/tags-is-less-more/281095#comment133863_281095) "three is the number thou shalt tag, and the number of the tagging shall be three. Four shalt thou not tag, neither tag thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out!"

Comment: I'm the one you're citing as advocating combining "master" tags with version-specific tags, yet I also completely endorse Jeff Atwood's viewpoint that we do not need a hierarchical tag system and do not believe that adding that sort of complexity would be beneficial. The explosion of [excel-\*] and [android-\*] tags is completely broken. Those are *very* different from version-specific tags.

Comment: Note, I think the problem with excel* tags is that [excel] exist at all. Excel is not on topic without software development, and the parts of excel that are unique to software development are more than capable of having their own tags. #excel-*FTW #excelsucks

Answer (score -4):

My take with "version specific" tags is that I don't see any point on them. No, your complete expertise in c# 3.0 is lost on c# 3.1, it's just *enriched*. So, lets get that out of the way.

Now, some topics are too broad that you can specialize yourself into a narrow point and still be able to have a sizable amount of knowledge to apply to diverse situations, lets use physics and quantum physics.

What happens is that instead of being the answerers that discover such broad topic, that while belonging to the physics topic, is also so narrow that you can do without the physicists and still be able to have people engaged asking and answering questions on quantum physics, that is where a new tag can be born.

Such happy little rose colored world was then tainted with asking any question on SO because *you are a programmer*, not because *you are doing software development* (the topicness of the site is defined by the task, not who executes it), and tags that didn't represent the topics you should ask about on SO proliferated, muddying the waters, and giving the idea that tags aren't that strict on their definitions. Mix that with #the #popularity #of #hashtags, and you have our current predicament.

People often confuse my desire to trim tags, to obliterate all tags, where that's not what I intend to do. Tags should be created when the question is asking about a topic that nobody on this site ever has. But also the topic should also be within our topicness boundaries. This two things should interact more closely with respect to tags, favoring topics(tags) that are unique to software developing. That would be more efficient and would assure that all questions find closure.

Comment: BTW, the comment on the question is just a joke. Some questions need 5 tags, some only 1. The content of the question is the thing that should decide the number, not our arbitrary metrics.