# Differentiating between [suitescript] and [suitescript2.0]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-disambiguation

As they are now, the two SuiteScript tags, [suitescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suitescript) and [suitescript2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suitescript2.0), create some ambiguity, specifically because many questions asking about 2.0 are still tagged only with [suitescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suitescript) and not [suitescript2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suitescript2.0).

I was not involved with SuiteScript at the time the 2.0 tag was created, so I'm not sure what the thought process was behind the organization of these two tags, but it seems that now either a 1.0 tag needs to be created or existing questions asking about 2.0 should be retagged in some way.

My main reason for asking about this is that there are tons of 2.0 questions out there that are hard to find because they're mixed in with 1.0 questions.

Could this warrant any action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unadorned tag doesn’t mean “version 1”. Rather, it means *all* versions. It is the generic, unspecified tag.

For questions *specifically* about version 2, the [suitescript2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suitescript2.0) tag should be used in combination with the [suitescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suitescript) tag.

*All* questions about SuiteScript should use the [suitescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suitescript) tag.

Note that this is nothing unique to SuiteScript or these tags. It is the general rule for version-specific tags. We prefer not creating or having version-specific tags at all, but sometimes they’re necessary when a particular new version introduces a major new feature and/or incompatibility.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379939/366904) for a bit more discussion on version-specific tags.

Comment: Right, but again, there are tons of 2.0 questions without the 2.0 tag which makes it difficult to search through _all_ 2.0 questions.

Comment: Are those questions about unique features of 2.0, or are they just general questions about SuiteScript where the asker *happens* to be using version 2? Tags describe the actual content of the question, not merely its context.

Comment: More often than not, they're concerning 2.0-specific features.

Comment: Then they might need to be retagged. Or, more easily, we could decide that there’s no need for a version-specific tag at all. In that case, a moderator could merge the two tags together and eliminate the need for a bunch of tedious retagging. I can’t decide if that’s warranted here, because I don’t even know what ScriptSuite is. :-)

Comment: It's definitely correct to have a 2.0 tag. Retagging all the stragglers might be a big task though. Haven't counted how many of them there are.

Comment: So could I retag any questions I find if I wanted to? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: @Adam, honestly, there is no way. We suffer the same problem in the python tag, albeit the numbers there are 150,000+, where here it is 300~. If you are worried about missing out some questions, the best way would be to favorite both the tags, and you should receive questions related to both of them in your view. Retagging every question after careful scrutiny, is just extra work.