# Do any tags automatically tag other tags?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

Let's say I have a visual studio question and I am running VS 2017. I always tag `visual-studio` & `visual-studio-2017` but I don't actually know if I need to - or if anyone watching the former will be notified of questions tagged with the latter?

If not, would this be a useful feature? Given the limit on tags, you can run out if you want to specify say VS and .NET version *and* something more specific.

Comment: No, there are no tags that automatically tag other tags. Yes, this would probably be a useful feature. Yes, you should almost always include the general tag when you use a version-specific tag. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379939

Comment: You can watch/search for `[visual-studio*]` so anyone interested in all the sizzle can do so. Questions that are about a feature specific to a certain version benefit from version tags to prevent that those questions popup at experts that only know visual-studio-2003.

Comment: Extending on that comment and answer from Cody: there are certain tags that have messed-up versioning. Adding the generic tag causes friction. Always check the tag wiki how the questions need to be tagged with respect to versioning. There is no one-size fits all. The tag system is very flexible in that sense.

Comment: Note that questions about .NET rarely need the Visual Studio tag, since there is usually a way to do the same thing from any text editor and the command line...