# Generic or Specific Tagging?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-search

In short, if a question for MariaDB 10.4 comes in, should I tag it as:

- As [mariadb-10.4] only,
- Or using the whole tree branch [sql] [mysql] [mariadb] [mariadb-10.4] ?

So far I've used the first criteria, but I'm not sure anymore. The first case makes it difficult to find the question, while the latter makes it easy to find, but may show too many non-specific results.

For example, this question ([Reverse Mysql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658150/reverse-mysql-query/61661543#61661543)) was originally tagged as [mysql] but it's actually a [mariadb-10.4] question so **I fixed** its tag. Good.

But this produces two issues when searching for it again:

**Intentionally Mis-tagging for Visibility**

Most people search for MySQL questions since it's more widespread than MariaDB's questions. These two database were very similar in the past but they are increasingly different nowadays. This may lead to people *purposedly* mistagging a MariaDB question as MySQL just to gain visibility.

**Should I Add The Version Number?**

Now, instead of tagging the question as [mariadb] I decided to tag it as [mariadb-10.4]; the version makes an important difference in terms of the repertoire of answers that can be provided: MariaDB 10.4 is a different animal compared to MariaDB 10.1.

But this, again, makes it difficult for people to seach for questions/answers when they search for the tag [mariadb]. It doesn't find questions for [mariadb-10.4].

So, bottom line:

- Is it better to just use the "leaf" tag of the hierarchy?
- Is it better to use the tag with the version number or without it?

Comment: Is the question and answer only relevant to 10.4? If yes, only tag with 10,4. If it might be used in other versions, use the overall mariadb tag. If it is a sql statement that is vendor agnostic add [tag:sql].

Comment: @rene So you are of the opinion of tagging with the **most specific** tag as possible that the question refers to.

Comment: Tag it as [postgresql]. <!-- ;-) -->

Answer (score 3):

#### If you use a version-specific tag, always add the general tag, too.

So, if you are going to tag something [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), then it should *also* be tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Similarly, if you are going to tag it [mariadb-10.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb-10.4), then it should *also* be tagged [mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb).

In other words: if you're adding a version-specific tag, always add the tag that is *not* version-specific. Crop off the version number, and add that one, too.

(It could be argued that this is not strictly necessary. When searching for questions to answer, either with an actual search or "favorited" tags, wildcards are supported. So MariaDB experts could find all questions tagged `mariadb*`, which would include questions that had only version-specific tags. But I still favor the general rule that version-specific tags should only be an *adjunct* to other tags. Version-specific tags are something that we permit only out of necessity and actually [prefer to avoid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379936/can-someone-explain-why-this-edit-was-approved/379939#379).)

#### Tagging more broadly than that is a judgment call, which you should make based on the desired answers and/or your knowledge of the topic.

If you're looking for an answer specific to MariaDB, then there's really no point in adding a general [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag. However, if you know (based on your subject-matter expertise) that the answer really has nothing in particular to do with MariaDB and just requires knowledge of SQL, then adding the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag makes good sense.

Note that the original asker is sometimes well-equipped to make these judgments (especially when it comes to using tags to indicate which types of answers they expect to receive); other times they are not—in particular, when it requires some sort of subject-matter expertise, or even knowing the answer in advance. For example, I might *think* that the question is specific to MariaDB when I ask and tag it, but if you come along to answer it, you may realize that it is really just a general SQL question. That's why we allow you, as the answerer, to edit and retag the question. That would be a good time to append the more general [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag.

Similarly, the asker may *think* that the question has general relevance to MySQL, given the shared history of MySQL and MariaDB. However, you, as the expert who comes along to answer it, may know better. You may know that it is something specific/unique to MariaDB. That would then be a good time for you to remove the general [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tag.

Another way to think about this that might perhaps be a bit easier to reason about is, should you add a [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag? Well, if it is somehow relevant to the answers that the asker is running on Linux, then yes, such a tag would be appropriate. However, if the solution to the problem is platform-neutral, then there is no point in adding an operating system tag. That just creates noise.

Remember the cardinal rule: tags should describe the *content* of the question, not its nature, milieu, or context. The principal purple of tags is to categorize and locate questions.