# Consolidating Python version-specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420115/should-we-add-the-python-tag-to-all-python-questions) about questions with [python-*] tags, but no [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. Adding the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag to all of the 200,000 or so questions in this category is not possible, so here's another solution ([original comment by
MisterMiyagi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420115/should-we-add-the-python-tag-to-all-python-questions?noredirect=1#comment924843_420133)):

- [python-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.1) (4), [python-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.2) (18), [python-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.3) (29), [python-2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.4) (222), [python-2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.5) (376), [python-2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6) (1291) and [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) (94,873) should all be synonymised to [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x).
- [python-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.1) (29), [python-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.2) (280), [python-3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.3) (978), [python-3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.4) (2242), [python-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.5) (2869), [python-3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.6) (4637), [python-3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.7) (3498), [python-3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.8) (1821), [python-3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.9) (792), [python-3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.10) (431) and [python-3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.11) (3) should all be synonymised to [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

(Note: I only counted the questions which did not have the target tag)

As [commented by zcoop98](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420115/should-we-add-the-python-tag-to-all-python-questions?noredirect=1#comment924707_420115), adding the minor version number is not helpful as a tag, and should instead be included in the body of the question, or in the title.

The difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is significant enough to warrant their own tags, but the changes made in minor versions are not.

This would also help watchers like me, as it is easier to just watch [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) than to watch all the minor versions as well.

Comment: Not to take away from the merit of actually implementing something like this, but to address your last paragraph about the difficulty of watching all the minor versions, it is worth noting that you can use wildcards in both favorite tags and tag searches. So, you can search for `[python*]` and get all tags that start with "python". (Which, incidentally, does highlight that, for the version-specific tags that *are* kept, there is a significant importance in ensuring that they follow a standard pattern. The Python tags already do, luckily. Surely not by accident.)

Comment: @CodyGray that would also add anything prefixed with python that isn't a version and [such tags overshadow version tags by a lot.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1632261) So no, there's no equivalence here.

Comment: Right, OK. You might need to get a *bit* more clever (not all that clever) and do something like `[python-3*]`.

Comment: "The difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is significant enough to warrant their own tags" the purpose of the tags is not to tell if there's any difference (example, we do not have html or js tags for versions of the specifications) but if those are enough to be their own topic altogether that someone answering one would have no idea how to answer the other. **They are rarely necessary and a pain to maintain**. I suppose it would take another 5 years to finally come around and remove those two too.

Comment: @CodyGray the point is that if you are doing that, you are doing it wrong. You should be searching for features or problems, not versions.

Comment: *but the changes made in minor versions are not* - I disagree. For example - look at the differences in how async stuff can be done between 3.4 - 3.6...

Comment: @JonClements - but **we don't need a separate tag for each minor version**. The OP can just add *I'm using Python [version]* into the question. People are tagging their questions with, for example, [python-3.5] **and not tagging it with [python]** (they see the version tag as a replacement to the master tag) - meaning answerers who just watch [python] don't see that question.

Comment: Well... the tag guidance does say: `The version of the Python programming language released on September 13, 2015. For issues that are specific to Python 3.5. Use the more generic [python] and [python-3.x] tags where possible.`... So one option would be to re-word that to always say to include `[python]`...

Comment: @JonClements - I doubt that would do much, as despite the tag guidance there are still [over 300,000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+or+python-3.6+or+python-3.7+or+python-3.5+or+python-3.4+or+python-3.8+or+python-3.3+or+python-3.9+or+python-3.10+or+python-3.2+or+python-3.1+or+python-3.11+-python+-python-3.x) tagged with [python-3.*] and neither [python] nor [python-3.x]

Comment: Indeed - who actually bothers reading tag info? :p However, I think syn'ing everything actually loses value and accessibility though. Something with a specific version tag is easier to specifically identify/filter on and/or add remove if needed to a post without scanning text for a version etc...

Comment: Although I do agree the version tags are misused frequently, they are still somewhat useful. I'd prefer this not be done currently and be revisited later once the [Version Labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers) feature is implemented.

Comment: @JonClements As far as I can tell, nobody reads tag guidance. I see tagging that blatantly contradicts the tag guidance, constantly. To the extent that that *doesn't* happen, it's *only* because the tags are sufficiently intuitive. But there are, for example, a huge number of questions in [tag:design-patterns] that are "please help me with my homework assignment to output a pretty pattern of asterisks/digit symbols at the terminal".

Comment: @JonClements When someone tries to tag a question, a short usage guidance summary pops up. Despite this, there are still many questions that get mistagged as `[python-3.x]`.

Comment: In [es.so] we have a warning saying something like _Use \[python\] for all the questions related to Python. If you think the question is specific to a certain version, do use also a tag like \[python-2.x\] or \[python-3.x\]..._ See [the Meta post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4014/83) where this was requested and implemented.

Comment: A complementary issue is the large number of old Python questions & answers that were written when Py 2 was dominant and which have no python-2* tag. Some of that info is still applicable to Py 3, perhaps with minor changes (like using the print function instead of the print statement, and input vs raw_input), but some of it is now obsolete, sub-optimal, or plain wrong. I suppose we can just advise newbies to avoid old Python questions, but that's complicated by the fact that many old Py 2 questions are popular dupe targets.

Comment: I'm curious what the situation is for other language tags - for example, does the Java tag have a problem with questions being tagged as just Java-8 without Java?

Comment: Minor version tags are theoretically useful for "Why does my code work in 3.x but not in 3.y?" questions.  However, it's clear that a *lot* of questions with minor-version tags don't really need to have them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Implement tag hierarchies instead.

The problem that you're getting at is easier solved with a tag hierarchy.

- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

  - [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)
  - [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

    - [python-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.1)
    - [python-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.2)

Then you would just tag the version that is *most* applicable to your question and

- searching would still work as intended.
- you wouldn't have to tag every parent tag.
- you would not lose data by eliminating a tag which *may* introduce a problem domain not applicable to earlier versions. Ie., [those searching for "generator functionality" may want *different* answers based on whether they're using 2.5 or 2.7](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420139/124486)

If you can structure it as a tree and it's not already a tree, you're probably solving someone's problem.

Comment: Or even just [improve the broken tag system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387405/help-new-users-by-making-tagging-smarter). The tagging system doesn't do a good job guiding users and it needs to be rethought.

Comment: [A very similar proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/325771) was made already in 2010 on meta.SE

Comment: @Adriaan IMO, that proposal is trying to use a hierarchy for way to much. It would already be really helpful (for this question and in general) if there was a way to express that a tag 100%, without a doubt, implies another tag. If there is *any* ambiguity, don't connect the tags. But you can't ask a question about [tag:python3.10] without asking a question about [tag:python].

Answer (score -7):

> The difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is significant enough to warrant their own tags, but the changes made in minor versions are not.

This sentence is plainly incorrect, especially in the context of Python 2. Even if we ignore any library changes and only look at new syntax between 2.5 and 2.7, there's generator expressions, the `with` statement, the ternary operator, unified `try` blocks (you could not use `finally` together with `except` before 2.5!), set literals, and much more. I would say for most questions the difference between 2.4 and 2.7 is bigger than 2.7 to 3.x.

I concede that the specific version doesn't matter for a lot of trivial questions. However, in these cases the python2/3 tags do not matter either - you can answer many basic questions with version-ambiguous code that runs on 2 and 3. However, the tags do matter for more complex questions which might benefit from advanced language features, or if OP is stuck with an old version where certain basic features (e.g. dict comprehensions) cannot be used.

For reference, I once had to edit my answer to a python question 3 times because it turned out OP was using the bundled jython 2.1 on IBM WebSphere. I'm not sure how long ago that was but IIRC jython 2.7 was already a thing. In that specific case, OP was unaware that it was a really old version, but a 2.1 tag on that question would have been tremendously helpful.

TLDR, the tags are useful if used correctly, so I don't like your suggestion of synonymising them to the 2/3.x tags. Optimally, all questions should have the generic `python` tag and add a version specific tag only if required. That's obviously not what happened, but removing the ability to disambiguate the versions is IMO not a good way to solve this.

---

This answer is way more contentious than assumed - potentially because it's mainly a rebuke of an argument for consolidation and offers no alternative ideas. Here's my personal take on how it could be cleaned up if a cleanup should be deemed necessary:

- Synonymize 2.7 to 2.x. That should be the default assumption for python 2 in most cases, and removes 95% of the tag volume for python2.
- Leave the other 2.x tags alone because they are useful to disambiguate older versions. If someone wants to ask a new question about 2.5, tagging as 2.5 is extremely helpful for answerers.
- I don't really care what you do with the 3.n tags. There's a few new syntax constructs (e.g. the 3.10 match/case statements) but these are IMO less impactful for most questions than the changes in the 2.n updates. Furthermore many of those features are new enough that most people would still prefix an answer with a disclaimer it only works in version x and up (e.g. 3.10 for case).

Comment: I think your Jython example actually highlights the opposite of what you want. Jython 2.7 is not fully compliant with Python 2.7 and incompatible with many libraries, so the minor version tag still is usually not sufficient for these situations. Just like the OP in your case, askers are usually not aware of such differences and could not select accurate tags even if we had/kept them.

Comment: "the tags do matter for more complex questions which might benefit from advanced language features" how common are those extreme examples? Are those questions being underserved if there's only one tag for them? Also, how are askers supposed to know when they are relevant? By the time people answers the question is already too late anyways.

Comment: (BTW, and putting yourself as example, out of 111 answers to python tagged questions, only 1 that you can recall where the tag could be arguably useful if the asker knew it is relevant)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi people being unaware about existing tags or the importance of version differences doesn't mean we should remove those tag from questions that already have them, though. And regarding jython, I would say a specific tag is only required for advanced questions or seriously outdated versions; otherwise it's compliant enough for most things. Not many people want to run libs with C extensions on jython in the first place.

Comment: @Braiam for starters, the tag is relevant if the version is outdated. And yes, the specific version matters - 2.5 vs 2.6 vs 2.7 can change file I/O, generators, comprehensions, etc, and more with even older versions. Furthermore, the tag should not be _removed_ from existing questions, which is AFAIK what happens with tag synonyms once they are merged. And regarding my answers, there are many more where the version was relevant, the example was the most egregious as I wrote a 2.6 answer which needed to be changed to 2.1.

Comment: @l4mpi That seems to be turning your own argument on its head. Your point is that *the answerer* benefits from the tags to know what can be used. But, say, a Python 2.7 tag would not tell anyone that a statistics question cannot be solved using NumPy because it's secretly a Jython question.

Comment: @l4mpi and that's relevant for me as a reader how? I can see how that could be relevant for answerers, but as an answerer, I should consider that before answering the question anyways (ie. my answer should be generic enough that it covers 98% of potential cases). Also, did you remove the 2.6 version of your answer just because the asker was using 2.1? Personally, I wouldn't.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi for starters, I'm saying a tag for 2.7 would not be needed in most cases regardless if it's jython or CPython etc. For lower versions such as 2.5 however, a specific tag would absolutely be preferable, and is IME more important than the jython/CPython distinction unless the question specifically lends itself to using libs with C extensions (yes, many people provide a numpy answer to literally every problem, but that's a different issue).

Comment: @Braiam that's e.g. relevant if you're writing code for IBM WebSphere (or some other legacy platform, or an OS that only has python 2.5, etc) and find an IBM WebSphere answer which provides code that you can run, not code written for later versions which use tons of syntax that simply does not exist in your version of the langauge. Again, _there are many many important syntax changes and additions in the 2.x versions_, thus the whole premise "minor version changes are not significant" is simply incorrect.

Comment: Again, why should I care as a reader about that? If I'm using ibm websphere version of python and I know that "ibm websphere" is relevant I would already include that in my query to search for information. If I don't find anything and am forced to ask, I would be damn sure to include that on the body of the question. In all those cases the tag wouldn't help me if I don't know what I should know. So, I ask again, when are those tag useful for the people that do not know the answer already?

Comment: "The deprecation of Python 2.5 support was announced on March 8, 2013 and support was permanently shut down on June 20, 2017." Why should we care about 2.5 then, since it's been unsupported for more than 5 years?

Comment: @EricDuminil Because systems running Python 2.5 still exist. LTS and legacy systems don't care about "unsupported" (yes, there's some irony for the former).

Comment: @Braiam you seem to misunderstand the websphere thing; it bundles a specific jython version and is not otherwise relevant (I know zero about it but was able to answer the q). Also, you focus on a reader (so, someone using SO to find existing solutions?) but for the reader no tag is relevant as long as they land on the right post via google. "Tags help connect experts with questions they will be able to answer" - and an expert would very much like to know if they're supposed to write code compliant with a recent python 3, or 2.7, 2.5 or earlier.

Comment: @Braiam Also: as a reader you might care about the version tag because it tells you what code the answer was written for. Q tagged 2.5? Answer is probably 2.5 code as well, if you're on 3.11 then maybe keep looking for newer answers. And otherwise, how does a 2.5 tag inconvenience a reader? Ofc the asker could include the version in the Q. But askers often don't do so unless prompted. Typing "python" in the tag box shows version specific tags as recommendations, which might cause some askers to add a version tag as well. If you synonymize all of the tags, this will no longer be the case.

Comment: @l4mpi no, I don't care what version the answer is writer for. I care if the answer works for _me_ and my use case. If there's an indication that the answer wouldn't work for me (ie. something like "for versions later than 2.6 use this instead") that would be another thing, but still the onus of the answerer to tell that to their readers. I write all my answers with the express purpose that anyone reading it, would be useful for them. You don't do that too? Writing for all potential implementations?

Comment: @Braiam "for all potential implementations" - lol no. First, there's a difference between "useful" and "optimal" or even "good". You can write python 2.1 code for reading files and use it in 3.11, but to do so would be a bad idea because you deprive yourself of context managers etc. To write "good" answers for all reasonably-used python versions (which includes at least 2.5 due to LTS linux  / unix versions) would be a big hassle. Same the other way around - if it's clear the question is about python2 (or e.g. jython which has no 3.x), answering with 3.x features is not useful.

Comment: @Braiam and again, you have not answered why a 2.n tag is an issue for you as a reader. If you don't care, nice, just ignore it. Don't deprive people of the ability to use it to make clear their question is about that specific version only.

Comment: @l4mpi great, "all reasonably-used python versions", exactly my point. I put that version for "all reasonably-used python versions" in the first, and then go down the poly-fill down the road of those answers. So, I provide you in order the best > the good > and the universally compatible. That assures me that unless you are literally going out of your way for a corner case, my answer would solve the question for any public.

Comment: @Braiam looking at your SO profile you hardly seem to provice any answers to python questions, and none follow your described approach. But it would not be useful in the first place. E.g. if the Q is how to read a named field from a CSV, writing four answers, one using `with` and `DictReader` for 2.7+, another working around the `DictReader` bugs in 2.6, a third for 2.5(?) where `DictReader` didn't exist, and one without the `with` statement for <=2.4, seems like a bad idea. As does writing answers without dict comprehensions (2.7+ only) unless OP specifies they're on 2.6 or lower.

Comment: @Braiam and I repeat myself, but you still have not answered how the python-2.n tags negatively affect you in any way.

Comment: FWIW, I do agree that minor version differences themselves are not insignificant. However, I would question whether tags are appropriate to provide this information. There are several things for which the information *may be* relevant (interpreter implementation and version, platform, dependencies, ...) *but*: the asker usually does not know which ones are *actually* relevant without knowing the answer already, and in sum these are too many to cram into tags (for example, just [tag:python]+[tag:python-2.7]+[tag:jython]+[tag:websphere] are four of the five tags allowed).

Comment: I'd do the same as with [tag:MATLAB]; tag it [tag:python] and, if warranted, [tag:python-2.x] or [tag:python-3.x] and have the OP mention their specific version and set-up (thus also OS, IDE etc) within the question itself if necessary. That way everything about either Python-2 or -3 is nicely bundled together, whilst preserving relevant information [tag:python-2.3] can definitely be relevant info, but hardly anyone will go watching that tag. Having it tagged python, python-2.x and mentioning 2.3 in the question body would suffice.

Comment: I agree with this answer: the difference between Python pre 2.7 and Python 2.7 is almost as significant as the jump from Python 2.x to Python 3. It's not just a step increment. And legacy systems are a fact of life. Keeping a tag distinction between Python 2.x and Python 3.x, but removing the distinction between pre and post 2.7 would be inconsistent.

Comment: @l4mpi "looking at your SO profile you hardly seem to provice any answers to python questions" because they are basically crap, that's besides the point. My argument is valid not only in python, but on every language to ever exist. People do not know what's relevant when asking questions, people writing answers should target as much public as possible. In my "limited" writing of python and non-python answers I live by that ideology and hasn't been a burden.

Comment: "For reference, I once had to edit my answer to a python question 3 times because it turned out OP was using the bundled jython 2.1 on IBM WebSphere." *Questions exist to help build a library, not to solve the asker's problem*.

Comment: @Braiam absolutely agreed. For that matter, Python questions are very often needlessly specific in the *input*, not just the environment. (For example: there are a ton of "how do I X with a tuple?" questions where the realistic answers map 1-to-1 with "how do I X with a list?".)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "Questions exist to help build a library" and the answer in that library needs to be different for differrent python versions. Or are you suggesting "how do I do task X with the built-in jython on websphere" should not be answered because the jython version is not recent enough?

Comment: @l4mpi I don't think nobody is suggesting that. It's suggesting that if the question changed, you are on no obligation to change your answer just to match it. But on those cases my preferred solution is "if you are using jy use this, if you are using pep python use this, if you are using X use this, ...." since the problem and solution share too much context that having one question for each jy, websphere or python only fragments the information.

Comment: @Braiam and as I told you before, I find your "preferred solution" utterly unworkable, and as far as I can see you've not written a single python answer in that way. If you actually tried to do so you would potentially find out why I think it's not useful.

Comment: @l4mpi "you've not written a single python answer in that way" because I've not had the need to :shrug:, you on the other hand have found yourself in that situation, and yet despite all that "experience" you still can't see how self defeating your way is.

Comment: @Braiam so let me get this straight - you still didn't answer my question how the python 2.x tags inconvenience you, continue to suggest an inane answering method despite not only never using it yourself but also never finding a situation yourself where it would have been appropriate, but are sure that it would have been totally appropriate for my situation... Yeah, your're simply not arguing in good faith here.

Comment: @l4mpi "how the python 2.x tags inconvenience you" let me get this straigh, since you still do not understand: tags have a very specific purpose, and version tags do not fulfill that purpose. Now, and before you tell me what purpose tag fulfill, let me ask you this question: in what way have tags allowed the success of stack exchange as a Q&A platform (spoiler: the first paragraph of the [help page](/help/tagging))? Also, is rich that I'm not arguing in good faith, when people repeatedly is ignoring basic axioms, like the one that would be set up once you answer the last question I asked.