# Can we have a message when someone posts a question tagged [python*] without a [python] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

(Sort of) related: [Should we add the [python] tag to all [python-*] questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420115/should-we-add-the-python-tag-to-all-python-questions)

---

In the Spanish version of Meta Stack Overflow, this feature was already requested and has been added (see [here](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3860/podemos-a%c3%b1adir-una-advertencia-en-las-preguntas-con-etiqueta-python/4014#4014))

It asked for a message to appear when someone tagged a question with a [python-*] tag (e.g. [python-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.5)) but not the master [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.

The message would go something like this:

> Use the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag for all questions you ask about Python. If you think your question is version specific, add a more specific tag as well as the above tag, like [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) or [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). If you are using a package like [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask), [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django), [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy), [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), or [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib), tag it in as well.

It would appear beneath the tags section, like this

[image: example]

---

This should stop the number of questions which are tagged [[python*] -[python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+-python+or+python-2.7+-python+or+python-requests+-python+or+python-imaging-library+-python+or+python-asyncio+-python+or+python-3.6+-python+or+-python+python-import+-python+or+python-multiprocessing+-python+or+python-3.7+-python+or+python-multithreading+-python+or+python-3.5+-python+or+python-sphinx+-python+or+python-unittest+-python+or+python-2.x+-python+or+python-3.4+-python+or+python-decorators+-python+or+python-3.8+-python+or+python-module+-python+or+python-xarray+-python+or+python-datetime+-python) from increasing.

Can we implement something like this?

Comment: The Spanish answer there mentions the big drawback (Google translate w/ edits): "Since the system does not currently have the ability to see the other tags that the question has, this message also appears if it has [python]". Not great.

Comment: @Laurel, I agree it's not ideal, but the first sentence is *"Use the [python] tag for all questions you ask about Python."* If they've already tagged it with [python] they can just ignore it and move on. If they haven't, however, then they tag the question with [python] and this may help answerers reach it quicker.

Comment: Yeah, I see this when editing tags on questions for [vba] or [sql] even though they already have the necessary tags. It's annoying, but very easy to ignore and continue on. Personally I'd rather have the message in that flawed implementation than not have any message at all.

Comment: I think I prefer the synonymization proposal from @MisterMiyagi.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, that wouldn't fix tags like [python-datetime]

Comment: Hmm, that's a much larger problem than I would have expected it to be. Hundreds of tagged `[python-imaging-library]` without any Python tag, for example.

Comment: Anyway, the overall guidance here looks good.